# Determine whether for loop is iterating over a list or a generator

Tags: python

Is there a way to tell whether, in python, you are iterating through a list or a generator?

```
for i in range(10):
     print some_param     # will identify as a list

for i in xrange(10):
     print some_param     # will identify as a generator
```

Comment: I'm curious: what are you going to do with the information?

Comment: Ah. I guess really just try to figure out whether the iterating item is a list or a generator. I was curious whether `for line in file` read the entire file into memory or just searched ahead for the next newline character.

Comment: `file.readline` does some buffering but certainly does not read the whole file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, no. You can do unpleasant things like `isinstance(my_iterable, type(iter(xrange(1))))` vs `isinstance(my_iterable, type(iter([])))`, but with the bare iterator interface, generators and lists are indistinguishable to their clients.